# Using instr-function in named range to filter certain string

Tags: vba, excel

My intention is to use the `Instr` function to check if there is an "x" in a named range, if yes then it triggers an event to hide another named range.

My code doesn't work, it shows

> Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

I tried to change the code to

`Set rng = Workbooks("Book1.xls").Names("suppliers").RefersToRange`

but that doesn't work either.

What is the reason?

My code:

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
enter code here
Set rng1 = ActiveWorkbook.Range("suppliers")
Set rng2 = ActiveWorkbook.Range("tohide")
For Each c In rng1
    If InStr(1, LCase(rng1), "x") <> 0 Then
    rng2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can avoid **converting** the text to `LCase` by using the `vbTextCompare` argument within `InStr()`. Any time you convert anything within VBA you are providing yourself with processor penalties - hence longer run times. May not be noticeable depending on how large your range is, but I would try to avoid unnecessary conversions. [More Info on InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)

Comment: Consider `Union`-ing the rows you want to hide, and then *after the loop has completed* you can hide all of them in a single, much more efficient instruction, e.g. `rowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll try to union the ranges after the looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You weren't using `c` in your `For` loop. Also your use of `Names` was fine so I've reinstated that.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range

    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("suppliers").RefersToRange
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Names("tohide").RefersToRange

    For Each c In rng1
        If InStr(1, c.Value, "x", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            rng2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

A `workbook` doesn't have a `Range`-method. You can access ranges only with a `worksheet` object. Assuming the named ranges are within the active sheet, you can use

```
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("suppliers")
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("tohide")
```

Comment: There is a small amount of irony to writing `ActiveSheet.Range()"... we qualify ranges to avoid VBA assuming we want to reference the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Sure, but the OP didn't give any information about his sheets - I just wanted to answer the question.

Comment: Completely agree - not a criticism!

Comment: @CallumDA I'll take *explicit* `ActiveSheet` references over implicit ones any day - the unqualified ones (e.g. `Range("foo")`) behave differently depending on whether the code is written in a worksheet's code-behind (where they're implicit references to `Me`) or in a standard code module (where they're implicit references to `ActiveSheet`). Code with explicit references to `ActiveSheet` works identically regardless of where it's written.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I'd say that's a tiny win in the grand scheme of things ;)

Comment: As a newbie, it's very interesting for me to read your discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds odd you have to hide the same range everytime a cell of another range meets some criteria

I mean I’d say you want to hide rows of to-hide range accordingly to the to-check range matching cells ones

Like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("suppliers").RefersToRange
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Names("tohide").RefersToRange

    For iRow = 1 to rng1.Rows.Count
        rng2.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Hidden = InStr(1, rng1.Rows(iRow).Value, "x", vbTextCompare) > 0 
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course, this assumes the two ranges have the same rows number